# When calculating proportion, is the total that I'm using to calculate it also the sample size?

Tags: proportion, sample, biostatistics

This probably has a very simple answer and I'm just overthinking it.

I have a very large dataset (~30,000 individuals), that contains data on casualties seen at a wildlife rehabilitation hospital. I'm working on finding proportions of recoveries based on different variables (i.e. what species they were, what age they were, etc.).

For example, there are 205 different species, and I'd like to calculate the proportion of adder snakes that survived. There ended up being only 1 adder and it lived. If I then want to calculate the proportion that survived it would be P=1/1 = 1, correct? As in, 100% of adders survived?

I'm to report my results with sample size, however, this is where I'm confusing myself. Is the sample size 1? Or is it 205 because there are 205 species? Or, even further, is it the almost 30,000 casualties included in the overall dataset?

As another example, for house mice, there were 11 casualties admitted, and 9 of them survived. I got a proportion of 0.81 for recovered mice. In this instance, would 11 be the sample size?

I think where I'm confusing myself is the graph I'm trying to make of the species with the highest rates of recovery. I wanted to add margins of errors to my graph, however with the adder snake I'm getting a margin of error of 19% due to my proportion (1), what I think is my sample size (1), and my confidence level (95%). It seems very odd to me to have an MoE of 19% so now I'm second-guessing myself.

Comment: What proportion do you want to discuss? If you want to talk about the proportion of adder snakes that survived, and one of one adder snakes survived, your proportion is of course $1$. If you had two adder snakes and one survives, your proportion would be $0.5$.

Comment: Hi Dave,
Thanks for your response. My question is more what is my sample size? Is the sample size for adder snakes 1? Or, in your example, where there are 2 adder snakes and proportion would = 0.5 because only 1 of the adder snakes survived, would the sample size then be 2? I'm just confused about what the sample size is defined as.

Comment: The sample size is the number of adder snakes. Think of it as successes out of opportunities. You had one opportunity for an adder snake to survive, and it did, so $1/1$. You had three at-bats in the baseball game and succeeded in getting a hit in one of those opportunities, so $1/3$. You flipped a coin ten times and got tails (success) four times, so $4/10$. Et cetera. // Or you could look at the proportion of surviving adder snakes that survived, which will always be $1$. While this seems silly, the math works out just fine.